# Why polysaccharides are not considered as lipids?

Tags: organic-chemistry, biochemistry, lipids

It is mentioned in my textbook that all lipids have one common trait which defines them :they are insoluble in water;they are hydropohic.
I want to ask ,since polysaccharides are also insoluble in water,what makes them not classified within lipids?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lipid https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polysaccharide

Comment: Like this your are going to classify all compounds insoluble in water in one big class whatever called. Say, hydrophobic water insoluble ones. Being polysaccharides insoluble in water might be their property but not the definition of them.

Comment: Polysaccharides are usually water-soluble.

Comment: Wood is not soluble in water and neither are stones. What is then the difference between wood and stones ?

Comment: Check your closest beginners’/general chem instruction lab. I bet they have starch solution.

Answer (score 2):

Suggest:  Solubility of either lipids, or (poly)saccharides may be affected by side groups and chains, the length and chemical nature of the later.  Instead, see how sub-units are joined together.  Typical lipids are *esters*, e.g. of glycerol:

[image]

([credit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lipid))

In polysaccarides, sub-units bind together as *polyethers* like [chitin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chitin) or [cellulose](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cellulose):

[image]

([enter link description here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polysaccharide))

And while sharing this structure motif, table sugar is well soluble in water, chitin and cellulose are not.  Not only because of different size of the molecules, but because of their peripheral substituents.